# Сохранение позиции после поворота

Tags: c#, c, unity3d

Есть код, который по движению джойстика(при условии, что `playerScr.controlType == Tank_controller.ControlType.Android`) поворачивает объект. После того как отпускаю джойстик, объект принимает исходное положение. Нужно как нибудь сохранить позицию после поворота.

```
public void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (playerScr.controlType == Tank_controller.ControlType.PC)
    {
        Vector3 difference = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ);
    }
    else if (playerScr.controlType == Tank_controller.ControlType.Android)
    {
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(JoystickMove.Vertical, JoystickMove.Horizontal) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ);
    }

}
```

Comment: Если в вопросе что либо не понятно, то дайте знать. Я могу непонятно выражаться

Comment: Посмотрите на свой код. Вы не просто меняете "transform.rotation", Вы **присваиваете** значение, зависящее от rotZ. Соответственно, если джойстик не двигается, то по итогу rotZ всё равно имеет какое-нибудь значение (скорее всего 0). Вам нужно не присваивать значение, а изменять (+дельта).

Comment: А как его изменять, а не присваивать то? Я не очень понял

Comment: грубо говоря: transform.rotation += delta (тождественно transform.rotation = transform.rotation + delta)

Answer (score 0):

Решение всё-таки нашёл. Нужно дополнить условие else if таким образом

```
else if (playerScr.controlType == Tank_controller.ControlType.Android && Mathf.Abs(joystickShoot.Horizontal) > 0.3f || Mathf.Abs(joystickShoot.Vertical) > 0.3f)
{
    float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(JoystickMove.Vertical, JoystickMove.Horizontal) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ);
}
```